# How do I change part of a word with wildcards, Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, search, documents, wildcards, replacement

I'm converting a timecode and need to replace a colon with a full stop -
00:00:00:000 needs to become 00:00:00.000

I've not used Wildcards before, but gave it ago with no success. What would I have to enter to just replace the last colon, as above?

Thank you!

Comment: [Finding and replacing characters using wildcards](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I've tried doing :([0-9]{3}) to specify I want the colon followed by 3 numbers replaced by a full stop, except that deletes the following numbers too. How do I just replace the colon?

Comment: You are almost there. Search for `:([0-9]{3})` and replace with `.\1`. Read https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm#Theory8

Comment: Fantastic, got it now, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 00:00:00:000 needs to become 00:00:00.000

Use the following:

- Find `:([0-9]{3})`
- Replace `.\1`

Source: [Finding and replacing characters using wildcards](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm)